# Copy to Clipboard on Windows 10 with Yank in Vim

Tags: windows, vim, clipboard

Clipboard support is working, however only the vim "dd" command copies text to the clipboard. I'm looking to have the "y" yank command copy to the clipboard. On an Ubuntu system this is working for me, however it is not working on a Windows 10 system. How can the "y" command be set to copy text to the clipboard on Windows 10?

echo('clipboard') returns 1, so there is clipboard support. The .vimrc file includes set clipboard=unnamedplus (may be some syntax errors here, however).

Comment: Hi @collinlacours, your question does not seem to be dev related. Maybe you would have better luck on the SuperUser Forum https://superuser.com/

Comment: Actually, [vi.se] and [ubuntu.se] have some experts too @JacquesRamsden  :) OP should perhaps read [ask] and learn how to format post

Comment: Hi @D.BenKnoble. I have up voted your comment as you make a valid point. That being said. Please don't mistake my comment as me making a statement that superuser is the 'only' place that can help It was basically just a point in the right direction....i.e SoF is possibly not the place you want to be :P. Any way good suggestions hope you come right collinlacours

Comment: @JacquesRamsden what's wrong with using stack overflow and the vi or vim tags?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried remapping `y` to instead be `"*y` which is "yank to clipboard register"?

These 2 lines will do that for you if you put them in your vimrc.
`nnoremap y "*y` (this line is for normal mode)
`vnoremap y "*y` (this line is for visual mode)

Comment: There will be more commands to remap such as the Y command. You can map those as you discover them.

Comment: Thanks - had seen that syntax around but did not realize yank needed to be set to yank to clipboard and that's how it's done. This worked.